# Do B1-visa-holders travelling to the US for business in May 2023 need to produce proof of COVID-19 booster dose?

Tags: usa, covid-19, b1-b2-visas, business-travel, vaccinations

Do people who are going to travel to the US in May 2023 for business (with a B1 visa) need to produce proof of COVID-19 booster dose? The traveler is COVID-19-vaccinated (initial two jabs done in 2020) but the traveler does not have any booster jabs after that. Does the US require the traveler to obtain booster jabs before traveling?

Comment: Nope, they won't ask about boosters.  Additionally the vaccination requirement for visitors to the US is expected to be dropped by mid May

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/proof-of-vaccination.html:

> **Are you Fully Vaccinated for Air Travel to the United States?**
>
> You are considered fully vaccinated:
>
> 2 weeks (14 days) after your dose of an accepted single-dose vaccine
> 2 weeks (14 days) after your second dose of an accepted 2-dose series
> 2 weeks (14 days) after you received the full series of an accepted
> COVID-19 vaccine (not placebo) in a clinical trial
> 2 weeks (14 days) after you received 2 doses of any “mix-and-match” combination of
> accepted COVID-19 vaccines administered at least 17 days apart*
>
> If you don’t meet these requirements, you are NOT considered fully
> vaccinated. **A booster dose is not needed to meet this requirement.**

Emphasis in the end is mine.

Check out the website for more details. If the vaccine you have been vaccinated with is accepted, then you should be okay.